# Matlab: Optimizing speed of function call and cosine sign-finding in a loop

Tags: matlab, eventtrigger, trigonometry, plane, dot-product

The code in question is here:

```
function k = whileloop(odefun,args)
    ...
    while (sign(costheta) == originalsign)
        y=y(:) + odefun(0,y(:),vars,param)*(dt); % Line 4
        costheta = dot(y-normpt,normvec);
        k = k + 1;
    end
    ...
end
```

and to clarify, odefun is F1.m, an m-file of mine. I pass it into the function that contains this while-loop. It's something like `whileloop(@F1,args)`. Line 4 in the code-block above is the Euler method.

The reason I'm using a while-loop is because I want to trigger upon the vector "y" crossing a plane defined by a point, "normpt", and the vector normal to the plane, "normvec".

Is there an easy change to this code that will speed it up dramatically? Should I attempt learning how to make mex files instead (for a speed increase)?

Edit:

Here is a rushed attempt at an example of what one could try to test with. I have not debugged this. It is to give you an idea:

```
%Save the following 3 lines in an m-file named "F1.m"
function ydot = F1(placeholder1,y,placeholder2,placeholder3)
    ydot = y/10;
end

%Run the following:
dt = 1.5e-12 %I do not know about this. You will have to experiment.
y0 = [.1,.1,.1];
normpt = [3,3,3];
normvec = [1,1,1];
originalsign = sign(dot(y0-normpt,normvec));
costheta = originalsign;
y = y0;
k = 0;
while (sign(costheta) == originalsign)
    y=y(:) + F1(0,y(:),0,0)*(dt); % Line 4
    costheta = dot(y-normpt,normvec);
    k = k + 1;
end
disp(k);
```

dt should be sufficiently small that it takes hundreds of thousands of iterations to trigger.

**Assume I must use the Euler method. I have a stochastic differential equation with state-dependent noise if you are curious as to why I tell you to take such an assumption.**

Comment: Can you put together an example with a built-in function and a test data set so it is easier for us to test different solutions?

Comment: If you replace `dot(y-normpt,normvec)` by  `sum(conj(y-normpt).*normvec)` you can save some `if`-`then` clauses. But make sure that all three vectors are column vectors.

Comment: It is still not clear how to use this example.  Make it so it can be copy-pasted and executed and it will work. (Please. :) )

Comment: I don't know if the conj is entirely necessary here. @H.Muster

Comment: @user1483329: I just copied what the function `dot` does (looked inside the function), thus, it is the same what you did before without all those `if`-`then`s within the `dot` function.

Comment: @H.Muster There does appear to be a speed-up, but I think for my purposes I can actually neglect conj as well. I usually deal with vectors of length 3 with all real numbers.

Comment: @user1483329: I checked the `dot` file again at it says that for two column vectors `a` and `b`, `dot(a,b)` is the same as `a'*b`. Hence, indeed no `conj` necessary in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would focus on your actual ODE integration.  The fewer steps you have to take, the faster the loop will run.  I would only worry about the speed of the sign check after you've optimized the actual integration method.

It looks like you're using the first-order explicit Euler method.  Have you tried a higher-order integrator or an implicit method?  Often you can increase the time step significantly.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, and highlights that I forgot a crucial piece of information. This is a stochastic ODE with state-dependent noise that requires the use of the Euler method for now. The math is a little too heavy for me right now to change it.

Comment: Your best bet is then to profile your code.  If `odefun` accounts for a large percentage of the execution time, then there's little to be gained from optimizing the sign check.  Use `profile on` to turn on the profiler, and `profile viewer` to view the results (nb: this also turns off the profiler).  If that's the case, then you need to optimize `odefun`.

Comment: I didn't even know about profiling code in matlab. This is sufficient help for now. The real F1 is quite complicated and sure enough could use optimizing as evidenced by the results from profiling.

Comment: Yeah, the profiler is decent, and has helped me quite a bit.  Best of luck tracking down the bottleneck.